# How do I append an output to existing rows?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, awk, sed

I'm running a command that outputs a list of numbers. I am using a for loop to run the command 5 times. For each output, I want to append those numbers to corresponding rows in an existing text file.

Command output:

```
# execute_command
20
30
480
50
```

Command with loop

```
for i in {1..5};
    # execute_command
```

Command output with loop

```
20
30
480
50
30
50
60
70
90
20
20
40
40
35
60
70
90
50
40
10
```

**Before**

This is just a text file I created.

```
cat:
rabbit:
car: 
can:
```

**After**

I want to append the command outputs to that existing text file.

first iteration

```
cat: 20
rabbit: 30
car: 480
can: 50
```

second iteration

```
cat: 20, 30
rabbit: 30, 50
car: 480, 60
can: 50, 70
```

third iteration

```
cat: 20, 30, 90
rabbit: 30, 50, 20
car: 480, 60, 20
can: 50, 70, 40
```

fourth iteration

```
cat: 20, 30, 90, 40, 
rabbit: 30, 50, 20, 35
car: 480, 60, 20, 60
can: 50, 70, 40, 70
```

fifth iteration

```
cat: 20, 30, 90, 40, 90 
rabbit: 30, 50, 20, 35, 50
car: 480, 60, 20, 60, 40
can: 50, 70, 40, 70, 10
```

Please help me. Thanks very much!

Comment: In the second and third iteration, where are you getting those numbers? From the command that outputs the list of numbers? If so, then how that command is working? Does it generate 4 random numbers each iteration?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Yes, in the second and third iteration, the numbers are the output of the command. The actual command is a benchmark that generates/outputs scores.

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide what your command actually does? Because I'm not sure if you have to call the command each iteration or maybe you call it just once

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I just updated the question with more details. The command itself executes once and I am running the command in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is pointer using `sed` and `paste` commands.

Your `base_file` (containing the column with `cat:`, `rabbit:` etc.) has four rows. You need to systematically "move" and paste the top four rows from your `numbers_list` (i.e. the output of your command) until the list is exhausted.

Consider the following command:

```bash
sed -n '1,4p' numbers_list | paste base_file -
```

which gives:

```
cat:    20
rabbit: 30
car:    480
can:    50
```

This output is your next `base_file`. You could put that in a temporary file called `nbase_file` with:

```bash
sed -n '1,4p' numbers_list | paste base_file - >nbase_file
```

then

```bash
mv nbase_file base_file
```

Now delete the top four lines in the `numbers_list`:

```bash
sed -i '1,4d' numbers_list
```

and repeat the process using a loop.

Note that the new items are pasted tab-separated. So you might like to use `-d ","` with `paste` command if you want comma as delimiter.